# Remove White Spaces Between HTML Sections

Tags: html, css

Please how do I remove the white spaces in between the html sections when page is rendered on the browser.

```html
<section id="product-overview">
  <h1>Get the freedom you deserve.</h1>
</section>

<footer class="main-footer">
  <nav>
    <ul class="footer-ul__list">
      <li class="footer__link">
        <a href="#">Support</a>
      </li>
      <li class="footer__link">
        <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: You probably didn't do a reset so the `h1` would probably have margins which will create space between section and footer

Answer (score 1):

Two of the HTML elements you used have `margin` by default. Both `h1` and `ul` tags come with `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` by default. You must either use a reset/normalize stylesheet or remember to account for the margins in your own CSS.

```css
#product-overview {
  background: #eee; /* just for demo so you can see the layout better */
}

#product-overview h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-footer {
  background: #ddd; /* just for demo so you can see the layout better */
}

.footer-ul__list {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="product-overview">
  <h1>Get the freedom you deserve.</h1>
</section>

<footer class="main-footer">
  <nav>
    <ul class="footer-ul__list">
      <li class="footer__link">
        <a href="#">Support</a>
      </li>
      <li class="footer__link">
        <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce the white spaces by removing the margins and padding;but choice is yours

```css
*{
padding:0%;
margin:0%;
}
```

```html
<section id="product-overview">
  <h1>Get the freedom you deserve.</h1>
</section>

<footer class="main-footer">
  <nav>
    <ul class="footer-ul__list">
      <li class="footer__link">
        <a href="#">Support</a>
      </li>
      <li class="footer__link">
        <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

`font` and `background color` you can set as per your requirement